# How to add index number of product in woocomerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem, and want to show in woocomerce product next:
1(first product) of 4(for example total count) and so on 2 of 4 ...

Total count of products I have, but how to show which index number it have I don't know.

```
                        function currentnumber(){
                            global $post;
                            $cat = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                            $key = $cat[0]->term_taxonomy_id;
                            $newcat = $cat[0]->count;
                            return $newcat;
                        };
```

Please review screenshot below, for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as nobody, answer:( i will leave my fix for this problem here, maybe it will help to smbdy in future

$product_ids = array (1,2,3);
   make product_ids array
array_search(get_the_ID(), $product_ids);
   then use array search function to get the index of the product id in the array